# Hi Im splitting a list into two and adding it to the main list...so How do i add the left out list data

Tags: java, split

Hi I'm splitting a List m getting into two...and adding it to the main list and I'm returning the main List....Now if I have 10 products with me..I get specifications for 10 products and am adding 7 to the main list....Now, how can I add the remaining 3 products Specs also to the main list

I have tried

```
public static List<List> getSpecData(Map<String, String> specifications)
{
    int count=0;
    List mainList = new ArrayList<List>();
    List l = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String s : specifications.keySet())
    { 
        l.add(specifications.get(s));
        if(count==7)
        {
            mainList.add(l);
            l = new ArrayList<String>();
            count=0;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return mainList;
}
```

Comment: You should post a sample of what you want

Comment: Are you sure the condition `if(count==7)` is correct??

Comment: Do you want to go from `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]` to `[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[8,9,0]]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another if condition for `if (count> 7)`, just like you did for count ==7.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague, but if you actually want what tobias_k suggests this should answer it:

```
public static List<List<String>> getSpecData(Map<String, String> specifications) {
    return createListOfLists(specifications.values(), 7)                    
}                                                                           


public static <T> List<List<T>> createListOfLists (Collection<T> values, int maxSize) {
    List<List<T>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<T>>();                   
    List<T> subList = new ArrayList<T>();                                   
    for (T value : values) {                                                
        if (subList.size() == maxSize) subList = new ArrayList<T>();        
        subList.add(value);                                                 
        if (subList.size() == 1) listOfLists.add(subList);                  
    }                                                                       
    return listOfLists;                                                     
}
```